# Is videoconvert unable to handle x-raw video in this case?

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to use a h264 video stream to be displayed in an app sink, when printing the pipeline I got this kind of behavior and didn't understand well what is happening, video is not displayed in this case. Is it a negotiation problem? Why the number of video/x-raw multiplexes to four?

[image: Pipeline Diagram]